# How do I change the number on the line in timeline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

I have the following code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (12,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,4/1,8/2,12/3}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- (\x,2mm)node[above]{$\$ 18,000$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That creates:

[image]

But I want to change $18000 to different numbers such as $18000 on 0, $19000 on 1, $20000 on 2, $21000 on 3.

How do I change the current code to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Needed is just small modification of your code fragment, i.e. write the desired numbers in the `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (12,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x/\y in {18000/0,19000/1,20000/2,21000/3}%
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (4*\y,-2mm) node[below] {\y} -- ++(0,4mm) node[above] {\$ \num{\x}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with the following slightly improved image code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (12,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x [count=\z from 0] in {18000,19000,20000,21000}%
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (4*\z,-2mm) node[below] {\y} -- ++(0,4mm) node[above] {\SI{\x}[\$]{}};
}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Very good. If I would have done it, it would have been spent centuries. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, no, no, you will done the same in few seconds. This time I was lucky that I see the question before you :-)

Comment: But that's absolutely not true. 

Answer (score 1):

It is useless here to iterate on two variables. Only one is enough, and to increment the dollar amounts, you just need to calculate the number of thousands of dollars with the evaluate option:

```
[evaluate=\x as \dollars using int(18+\x)]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{icomma}% <- Delete the space after a comma in a number in mathematical mode
\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (12,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \dollars using int(18+\x)]in {0,...,3}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x*4,-2mm)node[below](\x){\x} -- (\x*4,2mm)node[above]{$\$ \dollars,000$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```